# in device owner app for enterprise, does the flag.DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET also prevent hard reset from recovery?

Tags: java, android, device-owner

For device owner app for enterprise, does the `flag.DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET` also prevent hard reset from recovery?

`DevicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(ComponentName, DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET)`

Answer (score 1):

No, the DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET restriction does not prevent a user from executing "Wipe data/factory reset" from recovery. But recovery's factory reset is untrusted, so the FRP (factory reset protection) partition is not cleared. If you had a google account on the device, it will be required to sign in during the setup wizard. The FRP partition is cleared when doing a trusted factory reset from the settings menu in Android.